# Convergence a.s. implies convergence in $L^{1}$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty}X_{n} = X$ almost surely. Let $Y=\sup _{n}|X_{n}-X|$. 
Show that $Y < \infty$ almost surely, and define a new probability measure $Q$ by $Q(A)=\frac{1}{c}E\{1_{A}\frac{1}{1+Y}\}$, where $c=E\{\frac{1}{1+Y}\}$. Show that $X_{n}$ tends to $X$ in $L^{1}$ under the probability measure $Q$.

I'm trying to fit together all the definitions of convergence a.s., convergence in $L^{1}$, but I have absolutely no idea how to apply this to $Q$.

I would appreciate most sincerely any help you would give me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be helpful to know that for any random variable $Z$, we have $E_Q Z = \frac{1}{c} E \frac{Z}{1+Y}$.  You can prove this by first considering the case where $Z = 1_A$, then where $Z$ is a simple random variable, then an arbitrary nonnegative random variable (approximate $Z$ from below by simple random variables and use monotone convergence), then any random variable.

Comment: Prove what by first letting $Z=1_{A}$? I think the problem only wants us to consider that case?

Comment: Prove the first sentence of my comment.  (The case $Z = 1_A$ is just the definition of $Q$.)  But my suggestion is that you will ultimately want to apply it with $Z = |X_n - X|$.